# SSRS subtotals different in Report Preview vs when Deployed

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, preview

If I run a report within SSRS developer, I show no subtotals in specific rows, exactly as it should because there is nothing to subtotal.  However, if I deploy the report, those same rows have an erroneous subtotal in them.  I ensured I deployed and ran the correct report.  I even deleted the report and re-deployed.  I need to correct this because it is an important report that gets emailed to the entire company.

Comment: Usually when there's a difference after deployment, it's due to the report pointing to a different data source (different environment/server). Check the data source to make sure it's using the same db/server as expected.

Comment: It's the same data source.  I even re-deployed that just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe This is very classic case of Data been saved as Cache in your local System. But when you deploy the Report, there is actual Data available on application.

What you need to do is delete this FileName.rdl.data file and try your report again in Developer, it should get update data from application

[image]

Comment: I did try that.  Several times, even.  It still does it.

Comment: What exactly are you getting as Result. Could you paste Screenshot of your preview Result and actual result after deployment